# how to access an argument in a nested if statement from one function to another

Tags: python

Hi All I have a function with nested if statements. I am trying to access a variable within the nested if in another function. I have tried to globalize the variable in the function with the nested if to be able to access it in the other function but I get this error `local variable referenced before assignment` when I run the other function. Below is my same code for demonstration.

```
def add():
    global x
    a = 5 
    b = 6
    c = input(" ")

    if a and b:
       if c != 0:
          x = a + b + c
  
def sub():

    if a and b:
       if c != 0:
          y = x + 10  # I get local variable 'x' referenced before assignment on this line

add()
sub()

# I am not sure why I am getting that error since I have globalized variable "x"
```

Comment: What do you mean by if a and b ? it's not a logical condition any way

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this you'd better define the variables outside of the function and have the functions return the relevant values. Also make sure to convert the string that `input()` returns to `int`:

```
def add(a,b,c):
    if c != 0:
        return a + b + c
    else:
        print('invalid value')

def sub(c,x):
    if c != 0:
        return x + 10
    else:
        print('invalid value')

a = 5 
b = 6
c = int(input(" "))
x = add(a,b,c)
sub(c,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

global does not work the way you think it does.

before going into the function create a variable x not nested in anything.
then you can use global x in your function to modify it. if you just read the x it will find the global variable on its own if you assign x without specifying global in the nested function it will create a new variable.

```py
x =0
y=0
a = 5 
b = 6
c = input(" ")

def add():
    global x
    if a and b:
       if c != 0:
          x = a + b + c
  
def sub():
    global y
    if a and b:
       if c != 0:
          y = x + 10  # I get local variable 'x' referenced before assignment on this line

add()
sub()
```

Comment: I'll just add that since the function sub doesn't return y, and it's also not declared outside the function and then referenced as `global y`, the operation within function sub() has no effect, as the variable y is local only. Also, a and b aren't declared ad set earlier in sub, so the first of statement will always be False.

Comment: I have tried this suggestion with global inside the function, and assigning a value to the variable outside the function however I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
global x
a = 5
b = 6
c = 0

def add():

    c = int(input("Enter value of c: "))

    if a and b:
        if c != 0:
            x = a + b + c
            print('x=', x)

def sub():

    if a and b:
        if c != 0:
            y = x + 10  
            print('y=', y)

add()
sub()
```

Comment: I have tried this suggestion with global outside the function, however I get the same error